# webpack running with different errors on npm install

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, webpack

when I run `npm install` or `npm ci` that seems to trigger a webpack build which produces tons of incorrect errors. All of them referring to not found dependencies which are definitely there. In addition, `npm ci` seems to trigger even more of these errors than `npm install` does.

When I run webpack build, the build runs just fine however.
I am quite surprised by that behaviour as I don't seem to find any documentation on what's triggering this webpack run.

I'd like to better understand:

- what triggers webpack during `npm install`? (I would very much just like that to install dependencies)
- why does it show all these weird error messages?

I have installed:

- WSL 2 (Ubuntu 21.04) on Windows 11
- NPM 7.5.2
- Webpack ^5.65.0

Sample error output looks like this:

```
matthias@daiquiri:~/dev/hamster-books$ npm ci
asset main.js 42.9 KiB [emitted] (name: main)
asset index.html 2.91 KiB [emitted]
cached modules 3.96 KiB [cached] 4 modules
code generated modules 9.58 KiB [code generated]
  modules by path ./app/js/ui/ 6.5 KiB
    modules by path ./app/js/ui/*.js 1.45 KiB
      ./app/js/ui/loadingDialog.js 177 bytes [code generated]
      ./app/js/ui/ui.js 1.27 KiB [code generated]
    modules by path ./app/js/ui/_impl/*.js 5.05 KiB
      ./app/js/ui/_impl/createElement.js 480 bytes [code generated]
      ./app/js/ui/_impl/uiElementFactory.js 4.59 KiB [code generated]
  modules by path ./app/js/*.js 3.08 KiB
    ./app/js/hamstersBooks.js 629 bytes [code generated]
    ./app/js/dispatcher.js 2.47 KiB [code generated]
./node_modules/xdate/src/xdate.js 19.5 KiB [built]

LOG from webpack.FileSystemInfo
<w> Managed item /home/matthias/dev/hamster-books/node_modules/html-webpack-plugin isn't a directory or doesn't contain a package.json (see snapshot.managedPaths option)
<w> Managed item /home/matthias/dev/hamster-books/node_modules/style-loader isn't a directory or doesn't contain a package.json (see snapshot.managedPaths option)
<w> Managed item /home/matthias/dev/hamster-books/node_modules/css-loader isn't a directory or doesn't contain a package.json (see snapshot.managedPaths option)
<w> Managed item /home/matthias/dev/hamster-books/node_modules/less-loader isn't a directory or doesn't contain a package.json (see snapshot.managedPaths option)
<w> Managed item /home/matthias/dev/hamster-books/node_modules/xdate isn't a directory or doesn't contain a package.json (see snapshot.managedPaths option)
<w> Managed item /home/matthias/dev/hamster-books/node_modules/ts-loader isn't a directory or doesn't contain a package.json (see snapshot.managedPaths option)
+ 19 hidden lines

ERROR in ./app/js/dispatcher.js 2:32-75
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ts-loader' in '/home/matthias/dev/hamster-books'
 @ ./app/js/hamstersBooks.js 1:17-40

ERROR in ./app/js/dispatcher.js 3:40-69
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ts-loader' in '/home/matthias/dev/hamster-books'
 @ ./app/js/hamstersBooks.js 1:17-40

ERROR in ./app/js/dispatcher.js 4:34-81
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ts-loader' in '/home/matthias/dev/hamster-books'
 @ ./app/js/hamstersBooks.js 1:17-40
```

The output continues for a while after that, it's also repeating, trying to run webpack several times.I also checked - all these directories and files that are being referenced exist. It turns out some of them are coming from `node_modules` while other ones are just regular project references

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you try to wipe `node_modules` before running an install? Also, why are you installing using `ci`? Are you trying to see how the installation goes in a CI environment?

Comment: It would typically happen when some package has `install`, `postinstall` or some other NPM lifecycle script that is causing the Webpack build to trigger. Otherwise, there is no reason.

Comment: @Johnny deleting node_modules did the trick - now it is working. npm ci was used because actually that issue is coming from the script doing the release build. 
Thanks a lot! (if you want to give the suggestion as an answer, i am happy to mark is as correct )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wipe `node_modules` and reinstall. The reason for doing so is basically what  @Harshal Patil comment is all about, i.e. conflicts after packages trigger their install/postinstall scripts.

(This was the suggestion made in my comment, which solved the problem, now as answer so that it might be helpful for someone else with a similar issue)

Answer (score 0):

Incase it solves anyone's problem, our issue was the name of the package.. we had a package name @xxx, but the package name requirement is @yyy/xxx.. once renamed, warning was gone

I hope I save someone an hour (or two)